# pyenv: pip: command not found

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm trying to get Python 2.7 to play nicely with pyenv and virtualenv on OSX El Capitan.  I've installed `pyenv` with Homebrew, then Python 2.7.11 with `pyenv install 2.7.11`.  This describes the setup:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
$ head -1 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
#!/usr/local/bin/python
$ which pip
/Users/username/bin/pip
$ head -1 /Users/robinedwards/bin/pip
#!/usr/local/bin/python
$ pyenv install --list | grep 2.7.11
  2.7.11
```

`.bashrc` contains lines:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Now when I try to create a new virtualenv project:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 2.7.11 newproject
pyenv: pip: command not found
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you execute `source` command for your `.bashrc`?

Comment: It executes when I open bash - last line `echo .bashrc loaded` reports ok..

Comment: here's a related problem https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/71 may help you

Comment: @haifzhan But pip is already installed in the normal environment and just seems unavailable to pyenv..

Comment: Do a `type -a pyenv`.  It should report that pyenv is a shell function.  If not, then your evaluation of `pyenv init` somehow didn’t happen, and you need to take a closer look at your shell startup sequence.

Answer (score 35):

I'm not sure if that solution matches the problem, but after installing pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv and selecting a python version, I had to run `pip` that way:

```
$ pyenv exec pip install
```

Comment: I'm just curious. Any idea why we need to do this? It worked for me but I don't understand why

Comment: @A.A I'm guessing that `pip` is attached to a specific environnement, instead of being globally accessible. But not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my issue. It actually worked for running any command for example `jupyter notebook` after installing it

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error message. The problem was due to a failed installation of a python version, so `pip` wasn't found for this version. In fact, even `python` wasn't found.

example:

```bash
pyenv install 3.7.2 # this failed, but I did not realize it failed at first
pyenv versions | grep 3.7.2
```

> 3.7.2

```bash
pyenv local 3.7.2
python --version
```

> pyenv: python: command not found

So problem was not with `pip` itself, but a broken installation of a python version. Just make sure you succeed when you install a python version with `pyenv`.

Answer (score 15):

After installing a python version with pyenv with

```
pyenv install 3.7.13
```

I first had to run:

```
pyenv global 3.7.13
```

and now pip is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install `pip` separately if you didn't install `pyenv` from the binaries provided by [python.org](http://python.org)

After installing the wanted `python` version, download and install `pip` :

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
(sudo) python ./get-pip.py​
rm get-pip.py
```

> Ref: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 1):

I had a bad configuration using `zsh` and `pyenv`. I solved it by removing what I had in `~/.zshrc` on pyenv, removing the environment and python version (`pyenv uninstall 3.9.0` in my case) and then running the following:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

This comes directly from the provided `~/.pyenv/README` so I guess it should have been obvious. After reinstalling the python version (`pyenv install 3.9.0`) and creating the environment again (`pyenv virtualenv 3.9.0 my-env`) pip worked as expected when activating the environment via `pyenv activate my-env`