# Make `pypy3` command available without making `python` point to it

Tags: pyenv

With pyenv I can get multiple pythons installed. Currently when I do `pypy3`, I get

```
$ pypy3               
pyenv: pypy3: command not found

The `pypy3' command exists in these Python versions:
  pypy3.5-5.8.0
  pypy3.6-7.1.1
```

and if I do `pyenv shell pypy3.6-7.1.1` then `python` refers to `pypy3`. Is it possible to get only `pypy3` to refer to that installation?

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803857/pyenv-pip-command-not-found

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for.